# Not able to update field value on a record. Getting System.LimitException: Too many DML statements

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, soql, json, field-update

I want to update a field value through apex but getting error System.LimitException: Too many DML statements

Please find the code:

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)  
    public static AuraMethodResponse updateQuantity(String recordId, Object quantity){
        
        AuraMethodResponse res = new AuraMethodResponse();
        res.message = new Map<Object,Object>(); 
        
        try{
            Map<String,Object> quantityJSON = new Map<String,Object>(); 
            
            List<Object> quantityWrapper = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(quantity));
            
            System.debug('quantityWrapper-------->' + quantityWrapper);
            
            Double quantityValue; 
            Double SumQuantityValue = 0.0; 
            Double updatedAnnualVolume2; 
            Decimal productAnnualVolume;
            Integer sapAccountCount;
            
            for(Object obj: quantityWrapper){
                quantityJSON = (Map<String,Object>)obj;
                //splitQuantityValue =  quantityJSON.get('undefined'); 
                //quantityValue = double.valueof(splitQuantityValue);
                quantityValue = double.valueof(quantityJSON.get('quantity'));
               
                SumQuantityValue = SumQuantityValue + quantityValue;
                System.debug('SumQuantityValue-----> '+ SumQuantityValue);
            }
            
            OpportunityLineItem oppLineItemRecord = [SELECT Id, Name, Annual_Volume_2__c FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Id = :recordId];
            productAnnualVolume = oppLineItemRecord.Annual_Volume_2__c; 

            updatedAnnualVolume2 = SumQuantityValue + productAnnualVolume; 
            
            System.debug('updatedAnnualVolume2--------->' + updatedAnnualVolume2);
            
            oppLineItemRecord.Annual_Volume_2__c = updatedAnnualVolume2; 
            
            System.debug('Opportunity Product Annual Volume 2-------->' + oppLineItemRecord.Annual_Volume_2__c); 
            
            update oppLineItemRecord; //Need help here -- Getting System.limitException too many DML
            
            res.responseCode = 'Success'; 
            return res;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            res.responseCode = 'Error'; 
            res.message.put('ErrorMessage', e.getMessage()); 

            return res;
        }
    }
```

I would need to update the oppLineItemRecord with new Annual Volume calculated but getting error. Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Please read the linked Q&A for more details.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you for your reply. I checked the links which you have shared. It was really helpful. 
Thank you.